# Unable to vote to keep a question closed in the Reopen Votes review queue

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen

For the last few hours, I have been unable to vote to keep a question closed in the Reopen Votes review queue. If I do that, I get this error message:

> An error occurred when submitting your feedback. Please try again.

This occurs only if I try to vote to keep the question closed. No problem happens if I vote to reopen it. I had this problem on the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site. I don't know about other Stack Exchange sites, since I got no reviews from the Reopen Votes review queue anywhere else since this problem began.

Comment: Now fixed! (I think)